# next/router beforePopState not firing

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, next.js

As per title, `beforePopState` just doesn't fire when I hit the back button.

This code is a hook called in `_app.js` as per documentation.

Next version is 12.1.5

Anyone knows what the issue could be?

```ts
import { useEffect } from 'react';
import { type NextRouter, useRouter } from 'next/router';

const pushCurrentUrl = (url: string): void => {
  history.pushState({}, '', url);
};

export const useInterceptRouting = (): NextRouter => {
  const router = useRouter();

  useEffect(() => {
    router.events.on('routeChangeComplete', pushCurrentUrl);

    const beforePopState = (): void => {
      console.log('beforePopState');
    };

    router.beforePopState(() => {
      beforePopState();
      return false;
    });

    return () => {
      router.events.off('routeChangeComplete', pushCurrentUrl);
    };
  }, []);

  return router;
};
```

Answer (score 0):

I abandoned the idea of relying on next router and went fully native browser.
Keep in mind the actual browser support for all of this is flacky.

```js
const handleWindowClose = (event: BeforeUnloadEvent): string => {
  event.preventDefault();
  event.returnValue = dict.leaveCallConfirmation;
  return dict.leaveCallConfirmation;
};

export const redirectTo = (url: string): void => {
  window.removeEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);

  window.location.replace(url);
};

export const interceptRoutingChange = (): void => {
  window.addEventListener('beforeunload', handleWindowClose);
};
```

Then you call `interceptRoutingChange()` in your `_app` file.

And use `redirectTo` when you want to redirect the user w/o confirmation alert opening.